# classify_image function not being called as a function while running django

Tags: django, image, pytorch, classification

```
def classify_image(image_path) -> str:
    # Preprocess the image
    img = preprocess_image(image_path)
    
    # Make a prediction
    output = model(img)
    prediction = torch.argmax(output, 1)
    predicted_class = class_names[prediction.item()]
    
    return predicted_class
```

Error shows TypeError at /
'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable

It shows error in line

```
output = model(img)
```

```
Exception Location: C:\Users\krishna sahu\PycharmProjects\Plant-Disease-Classification-Pytorch\PlantDisease\ImageApp\views.py, line 38, in classify_image
```

What should be correct solution for this error.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Where does the model variable come from? Python thinks it is an OrderedDict. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: model variable is a pytorch model, saved as .pth file